# Regex expression to see if a file path matches a particular pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of file paths

```
l = ['C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompteBo\\saisie\\saisieCompteBo-flux.xml',
     'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\recherche-flux.xml', 
     'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompteBo\\import\\import-flux.xml',
     'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\gestionCompteBo-flux.xml', 
     'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompte\\gestionCompte-flux.xml', 
     'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCommunication\\tableauDeBord\\tableauDeBord.xml']
```

I need to fetch those file paths which match the pattern

```
pattern = '\\WEB-INF\\flows\\**\\*-flux.xml'
```

where `**` depicts recursive depth of folders/directories.
`*` may depict just one folder deep.
How do I write a regex expression to fetch the file paths that match this pattern? How do I generalise if there is a single `*`?

Expected output should be

```
['C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompteBo\\saisie\\saisieCompteBo-flux.xml',
 'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompteBo\\import\\import-flux.xml',
```

Comment: use `glob.glob` with `pattern = '\WEB-INF\flows\**\*-flux.xml'` that will work

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: `glob` works on actual directories, not on strings.

Comment: Please show what you have already tried.

Comment: yes. XY problem too soon :)

Comment: I get `['C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompteBo\\saisie\\saisieCompteBo-flux.xml',
 'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompteBo\\import\\import-flux.xml',
 'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompte\\gestionCompte-flux.xml']` with your filter

Comment: I don't understand how you are not supposed to get at least 3 results in your output from your example the: `C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompte\\gestionCompte-flux.xml` also matches what you want right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your pattern could be easily converted to regular expression:

```
r'\\WEB-INF\\flows\\.*\\.*-flux\.xml'
```

- raw prefix to protect the slashes
- pick anything between backslashes (including backslashes) with `\\.*\\`
- pick anything ending with `flux.xml` (note the protection of the `.`). No need to filter out backslash or use non-greediness, because evaluation is done from left to right.

like this:

```
import re

l = ['C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompteBo\\saisie\\saisieCompteBo-flux.xml',
     'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\recherche-flux.xml',
     'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompteBo\\import\\import-flux.xml',
     'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\gestionCompteBo-flux.xml',
     'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompte\\gestionCompte-flux.xml',
     'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCommunication\\tableauDeBord\\tableauDeBord.xml']

result = [x for x in l if re.search(r'\\WEB-INF\\flows\\.*\\.*-flux.xml',x)]
```

result:

```
>>> result
['C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompteBo\\saisie\\saisieCompteBo-flux.xml',
 'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompteBo\\import\\import-flux.xml',
 'C:\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\flows\\gestionCompte\\gestionCompte-flux.xml']
```

Comment: You'd want to match `[^\\]*` instead of `.*` for a plain `*`, as opposed to `**`.

Comment: And no, greediness has nothing to do with it, because *the moment a pattern doesn't use `**` in the path*, you still want to only match non-path components.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think OP doesn't have `*` in the paths. It's just a matter of wildcard => regex conversion. I was mentionning greediness because if you do `r'\\WEB-INF\\flows\\.*?\\.*-flux\.xml'`, well, it will also work... but with an extra requirement on the start of the filename like `r'\\WEB-INF\\flows\\.*?\\gestion.*-flux\.xml'` it would not.

Comment: Yes, exactly, and `*-flux.xml` is properly translated to `[^\\]*-flux\.xml` in the *general case*, e.g. when matching `\\WEB-INF\\flows\\*.flux.xml`, or `\\**\\flows\\*-flux\.xml`. Note how the latter also uses `**` but should not match *any* of the deeper `gestion*` directories!